# GDAL to generate MVT from multiple PostgreSQL tables

Tags: gdal, postgresql, ogr2ogr, vector-tiles

I have a number of spatial tables in my PostgreSQL database which I would like to tile cache to Vector Tiles. Is it possible to combine multiple tables in one go so that effectively each tile has content of many tables/layers?

After researching the ogr2ogr documentation it looks like it is possible for one layer, but I cannot figure out how to set things up for many layers?
Are there any examples please how to generate MVT from Postgres using ogr2ogr / how to set the params?

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of digging this command does what I need:

> ogr2ogr -f MVT  tilesdir  -dsco CONF=config.json -dsco MINZOOM=11
> -dsco MAXZOOM=16 -dsco COMPRESS=NO PG:"host=myhost dbname=mydb user=myuser password=mypass" tablea tableb tablec

Above pulls 3 tables: tablea tableb tablec

Then in my *config.json* the table names become the keys as in the sample provided in the documentation:

https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mvt.html